# Session Timeout module

Tags: 7, sessions, users

What's the best module for a session timeout?

I simply want users to be automatically timed out after a period of inactivity.

The [Automated Logout](https://drupal.org/project/autologout) module looked like it could to the trick, but it seems like it does a lot more too.  Also, I am using Drupal 7 and it's still in dev.

Comment: Autologout now has a proper drupal 7 release and works as advertise.

Answer (score 6):

You have two options in the settings file that should allow you to configure the session timeout however you wish, [`session.gc_maxlifetime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) & [`session.cookie_lifetime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime).

```
/**
 * Set session lifetime (in seconds), i.e. the time from the user's last visit
 * to the active session may be deleted by the session garbage collector. When
 * a session is deleted, authenticated users are logged out, and the contents
 * of the user's $_SESSION variable is discarded.
 */
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 200000);



 /**
  * Set session cookie lifetime (in seconds), i.e. the time from the session is
  * created to the cookie expires, i.e. when the browser is expected to discard
  * the cookie. The value 0 means "until the browser is closed".
  */
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 2000000);
```

Comment: Also it's worthwhile to try the session_expire module (https://drupal.org/project/session_expire) which sets expiration so that it will really work.

Comment: More explanation on these variables http://stackoverflow.com/q/520237